# Getting the value of the drop down parameter Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I get the drop down value inside the form with `select("select", "trader", @unique_traders) %>`

Inside the controller I try to get the value of the actual trader, but I was only able to retrieve a value in such format from:

```
@val = params[:select]
> {"trader" => "ALL"}
```

And attempts to do something like `params[:select[:trader]]` and `params[:select["trader]]` return blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@val = params[:select]['trader']
```